# Using ASP:CompareValidator to compare a ASP:DropDownList against a literal value

Tags: asp.net, html-select, comparevalidator

We are implementing an ASP:CompareValidator and it's not working as we were expecting.

On the form there is an ASP:DropDownList where one of the items in the DropDown is:

```
<Please select a class>
```

That text also includes the angle brakets.

We want to make sure the user selects something from the DropDown so we don't want the data saved while the DropDown shows:

```
<Please select a class>
```

Can you check my markup and let me know why the validation error message is showing up when the user clicks the Update button?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class:">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList 
            ID="DropDownListClass" 
            Runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
            DataTextField = "ClassName"
            DataValueField="ID"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
            ForeColor="Blue">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:CompareValidator 
            runat="server" 
            id="ClassMustBeSelected" 
            controltovalidate="DropDownListClass" 
            ValueToCompare="<Please select a class>"
            operator="Equal" 
            type="String" 
            errormessage="Please select a class!">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The values for the DropDown are from this DataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSourceClasses" 
    runat="server" 

    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Knowledge Academy %>" 

    SelectCommand=
        "SELECT '' AS ID, '<Please select a class>' AS ClassName, '' AS Grade
   UNION SELECT ID, ClassName + ' *** Grade: ' + Grade AS ClassName, Grade 
           FROM Classes
       ORDER BY 2, 3">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fields that must hava a value in them before the form is submitted should use the required field validator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78xxk8k(v=VS.71).aspx

Note the following from microsoft

**Note   If the input control is empty, no validation functions are called and validation succeeds. Use a RequiredFieldValidator control to prevent the user from skipping an input control.**

So you need both a required field validator and a compare validator for this to work (although normally just leaving the list blank (unselected) and using a required field validator is usually what's done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Each item in the DropDown actually has a value. The 1st. item in the DropDown is the text inside the angle brackets. The rest of the items are from the database. I will update the posting to include the DataSource so you can see the actual values.

Comment: Could I be missing one of the CompareValidator elements?

Comment: +1 The highlighted part about the "empty" control (despite it being a dropdownlist) was exactly what I needed. Converted from Compare to RequiredField worked for me